# How to JavaDoc a record without warnings from -Xdoclint?

Tags: java, warnings, javadoc, false-positive

I have been trying to familiarize myself with records, but I ran into something that really looks like a bug in Java's tool for linting JavaDoc -Xdoclint.

I tried to use this command...

```
 javac     -Xdoclint:all       XdoclintDoesntHandleRecordJavadocCorrectly.java
```

...to lint my JavaDoc for this file...

```
/**
 *
 * Comment.
 *
 * @param a Comment.
 * @param b Comment.
 * @param c Comment.
 *
 */
public record XdoclintDoesntHandleRecordJavadocCorrectly(
/** Comment. */
int a,
/** b Comment. */
int b,
/** @param c Comment. */
int c
) {}
```

...which gave me this error...

```
XdoclintDoesntHandleRecordJavadocCorrectly.java:14: warning: no comment
int a,
    ^
XdoclintDoesntHandleRecordJavadocCorrectly.java:16: warning: no comment
int b,
    ^
XdoclintDoesntHandleRecordJavadocCorrectly.java:18: warning: no comment
int c
    ^
3 warnings
```

...which makes no sense to me at all.

Is this a bug in Java's -Xdoclint tool? Normally, I wouldn't be so quick to make the claim, but [this isn't the first time that -Xdoclint tool has had bugs that Java later fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67010921/javadoc-xdoclint-keeps-flagging-my-optional-anonymous-class-for-not-having-a#comment119093896_67055965).

And finally, here is my java version.

```
$ java --version
java 18 2022-03-22
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 18+36-2087)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 18+36-2087, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the [Javadoc example for records in the OpenJDK repository](https://github.com/openjdk/valhalla/blob/lworld/test/langtools/jdk/javadoc/doclet/testRecordTypes/examples/Point.java) gives the same warning, this is certainly a bug.

edit: The [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.10.3) provides a clue:

> For each record component, a record class has a field with the same name as the record component and the same type as the declared type of the record component. This field, which is declared implicitly, is known as a component field.

So "no comment" could well refer to this *implicitly declared component field* of the record *class* that results from the record and cannot be commented, similar to [the findings from the issue you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67055965/833399).

Comment: Although the maintainers seem to be aware of this warning and even [included it in one of the integration tests](https://github.com/openjdk/valhalla/blob/lworld/test/langtools/jdk/javadoc/doclet/testRecordTypes/TestRecordTypes.java#L579).

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a well researched answer that proves its point well. I wanted to make sure I wasn't wrong before pushing forward. I would award the bounty now, but StackOverflow is telling me I have to wait 18 hours.

Comment: Thank you again! I am going to submit this as a bug to Oracle, and hope that they resolve this, much like they did the other one.

Comment: Submitted a bug to Oracle, and they finally created a ticket for it, but they immediately resolved it because they did not follow the directions I asked them to, and thus, didn't get the warning that we both found. Though, in their defense, I put this under the wrong ticket subcomponent, so I understand the confusion. You can follow along here -- https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8284994

Comment: The problem has been resolved, and it is coming out in Java 19! Thank you again! https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8284994