# javadoc fails in presence of imports in module-info.java

Tags: java, javadoc

I am sometimes generating my own javadoc of OpenJDK modules to adjust the `javadoc` command with my favorite options. Recently I tried to do this for OpenJDK 20 but got strange module-not-found-errors for some modules. I pinned the issue down to the following (almost) minimal command, e.g. for the `java.management` module:

```
.../jdk-20.0.2/bin/javadoc -sourcepath .../jdk-jdk-20-ga/src/java.management/share/classes -subpackages com:java:javax:sun --module java.management -verbose
```

That results in:

```
[parsing started SimpleFileObject[.../jdk-jdk-20-ga/src/java.management/share/classes/module-info.java]]
[parsing completed 22ms]
error: module java.management not found on source path
1 error
```

So I checked out `.../java.management/share/classes/module-info.java` and it contains since OpenJDK 20 an import and an `@ParticipatesInPreview` annotation:

```
import jdk.internal.javac.ParticipatesInPreview;

/**
...
 */
@ParticipatesInPreview
module java.management {
```

If I remove that annotation and the corresponding import, things work like expected. The main issue appears to be the import rather than the annotation. For other modules I got a similar failure just in presence of imports rather than an annotation.

My question: How can I adjust the `javadoc` call to succeed properly if imports (and maybe `@ParticipatesInPreview`) are present?

I already played around with some options, e.g. setting `-source` or `--release` with `--enable-preview` or add the module `jdk.compiler` via `--add-module` because that module hosts the import. So far nothing I tried did the trick.

**Update:**
Since a few days ago JDK 21 reached GA status, I repeated this on JDK 21 and the issue is the same as in 20. However, `java.management` is not affected any more because they removed the imports. AFAICT no `java.*` `module-info.java` file contains imports in JDK 21, but the issue can still be reproduced e.g. on `jdk.compiler`:

```
.../jdk-21/bin/javadoc -sourcepath .../jdk-jdk-21-ga/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes -subpackages com:jdk:sun --module jdk.compiler -verbose
[parsing started SimpleFileObject[.../jdk-jdk-21-ga/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/module-info.java]]
[parsing completed 38ms]
error: module jdk.compiler not found on source path
1 error
```

Like before, removing the imports makes it work.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `java.management`, so my first instinct would be to make sure it is actually something that is bundled with the JDK. For example, JavaFX is not bundled with the JDK. But if not that, it's not impossible that this is a bug in Java. I have successfully reported multiple bugs in JavaDoc. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67010921/javadoc-xdoclint-keeps-flagging-my-optional-anonymous-class-for-not-having-a and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71726595/how-to-javadoc-a-record-without-warnings-from-xdoclint

Comment: @davidalayachew `java.management` is included in Java, see https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/

Comment: @davidalayachew A bug in javadoc is also my thought. At very least, the error message should be improved. I just thought that doing some deeper usage research, including asking this question here, would be good practice before filing a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the observed behavior is a bug in Javadoc. A corresponding bug report has been accepted under https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=JDK-8317289.